# my model is always gives same prediction value

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i trained and predicted ranking using gru layers.
but it always gives same prediction value even input changed.
for example, 
input (1,2,3,5) -> 6
input (2,4,6,9) -> 6

what is wrong in my model?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(32, batch_input_shape = (1,6,1), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(GRU(16, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(GRU(8, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, stateful = True))
model.add(GRU(4, activation ='relu', stateful = True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x[train], y[train], epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stopping_callback, checkpointer],
           validation_data = (x[test], y[test]))
```

Comment: is there a reason you're `stateful=True`? and changing activation to `relu`?

Comment: @thushv89 so you mean i have to change stateful option?

Comment: I recently got a similar error. My problem was that there were nan-values within my training data. This sometimes leads the loss to become nan, but it did not in my case. In the end I got rid off these strange values and prediction worked properly. Maybe you got a similar problem.

Comment: @Solvalou thank you for your comment. but my data doesn't have a nan data...

Comment: What kind of data do you have? If class "6" is highly imbalanced (there are way more instances of that class in dataset than any other) than model may learn to predict only that class.

Comment: @Ach113 As you say, my y-data is 1,616 for 2, 4,976 for 3,307 for 5, 107 for 8, and 104 for 13. And the forecast always comes in second.